# Is there a limit on outbound TCP connections to many IP addresses?

Tags: windows, azure, .net-core, tcp

I know there are many related questions about this topic already, but none I can find provide a definitive answer to this question:

I have a TCP server (.NET core running on Windows) that acts as a proxy from ~1.000.000 unique clients to ~500.000 unique services. I'll call the proxy P, the clients of the proxy C and the services behind the proxy S.

When P acts as a server for C, it listens on a single IP address on port 1433. What I read is that when acting as a server apparently a TCP connection is uniquely identified by the 4-tuple (local ip, local port, remote ip, remote port), so connecting 1.000.000 unique C to P should not be a problem.

Being a proxy server, P also acts as a client to S. Every S has a unique IP address. It appears to me that outbound connections should work exactly the same as inbound connections, namely: a connection is identified by the aforementioned 4-tuple, and since every S has a unique IP address, setting up 500.000 outbound connections should be no problem.

However, I am finding conflicting information: Some sources make it appear as though outbound connections work differently from inbound connections, in that for outbound connections the local ip and port combination must be unique, so I will run out of ephemeral ports after max. 64K connections. This seams like a strange asymmetry between inbound and outbound connections to me. The proposed solution here is to use multiple IP addresses for outbound connections.

Is my understanding that there is an asymmetry correct? And if so, why is that? And is there a way to overcome the outbound connection limitation? If it is of any influence on possible solutions: The proxy will be deployed to Azure.

Comment: See http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html

Comment: It's more of an OS limit than anything else.

Comment: @Tarik thanks for that link, but it doesn't explain the origin of the asymmetry that is there and doesn't provide possible solutions. Also, you say it's an OS limit, but what are you actually referring to here? Is the inability to use a single ephemeral port for connections to multiple unique remote ip/port combinations?